# JavaScript Square Object

Tags: javascript

In Java Script, how do you create a square object with the only attribute being the length of one side and the only method is get Area() which returns the area (length squared)

Comment: Show us what u tried so far ;)

Comment: Not even sure where to start

Comment: What is difficult? Do you know how to represent an object in js?

Comment: I'm not sure how to create the object and I'm familiar with some of the methods and the side.length, but I don't know how to turn that into code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an Object you can use a function as constructor and the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyworkd

```
function Square (length) {
    this.length = length;
}
```

*When called, the construcotr assigns the parameter (`length`) it got called with, to the new Objects `length` property*

*`this`  in this case refers to the new Object*
*You might also want to read MDNs article about the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword*

Now that we have an constructor, we can assign a method to the function `Square`'s [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

which gehts shared by its instances, once created

```
Square.prototype.getArea = function () {
    return this.length * this.length; 
}
```

*This simply returns the square of the `length` property of the Object it got called from*

And to actually create you "Square" Object you can create a new instance using `new` and the constructor `Square`

```
var mySquare = new Square(4);
```

Now `mySquare` holds an instance of `Square`.  And you can for example log the result of the `getArea` method

```
console.log(mySquare.getArea()) //16;
```

Here is an example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uxewey/1/edit)